# Recursively Capitalize all Files and Directories within a Given Directory PHP or Commandline

Tags: php, rename

I need to properly title case all the directories and files inside my application folder as I'm moving my app to PSR-0 with namespacing.

I'm sure there's an elegant way in either php or via the commandline (Mac OSX) to accomplish this without spending hours doing it.

My structure looks like so:

```
application
    admin
        controller
            dir1
                file.php
            dir2
                file.php
            ...
        language
            english
                english.php
                dir1
                    file.php
                    ...
                dir2
                    file.php
                ...
        model
            dir1
                file.php
                ...
            dir2
                file.php
                ...
            ...
    public
        ...
```

I tried using glob but that gives me the full file paths and doesn't seem to change the actual directory name or file name.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Show the `glob`.  You need the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you use the RecursiveDirectoryIterator. Documentation can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

```
<?php

$path = realpath('PATH_TO_STARTING_DIRECTORY'); // replace with the real path

$items = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), 
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

// Loop through first time & change files
foreach($items as $name => $f){
    if (!is_dir($f)) {
        // If you want to be all caps use
        strtoupper(trim($f));

        // If you want to be only first letter caps
        ucwords(trim($f));
    }
}

// Loop through a second time & change directories
foreach($items as $name => $d) {
    if (is_dir($d) && ('.' != $d && '..' != $d)) {
        // If you want to be all caps use
        strtoupper(trim($d));

        // If you want to be only first letter caps
        ucwords(trim($d));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This looks very close. I'm getting . and .. in the array. Once I get if filtered out then just use rename() on the results?

Comment: Still not quite there ... files need to be completed first, then directories otherwise the files to rename won't be found. Maybe loop through and add directories and files to different arrays, then rename them in 2 passes?

Comment: Loop twice, first with !is_dir($dirOrFile) to rename files only, second time with is_dir($dirOrFile) to rename directories only